# Get access to the context element of a dynamically bound event inside the event handler in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have piece of html that is injected into the page and dynamically bound to a click event handler. As shown in the code below

```
 var matchMore = $(".match-more-btn");

 matchList.on("click", matchMore, function() {
   var self = $(this); //<--- Problem here
   matchFunc(self);
 });
```

My problem is that I want to get the object passed in as the context (ie: dynamically bound element, the `matchMore` element shown above) but 'this' returns `matchList` object. How do I get access to the element that initiated the event

Comment: Use `event.target`

Comment: Thanks @Setpal, it works

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery documentation at http://api.jquery.com/on/ states:

> event.target indicates the deepest (innermost) element where the event
>   occurred.

```
var matchMore = $(".match-more-btn");

matchList.on("click", matchMore, function(event) {
    var self = event.target;
    matchFunc(self);
});
```